# How do I select which columns from my CSV to chart with HighChart?

Tags: csv, highcharts

I am trying to create a graph from a CSV file that contains multiple data values for each time value.  I would like to graph two of those data points, but have not been able to figure out how to import the CSV file into an array.

Here is a sample of my CSV

```
Year,Month,Day,Hour,Time,kWh,Savings,Total kWh
2013,02,06,11,11:00,0,0,308135
2013,02,06,11,11:59,15,1.875,308150
2013,02,06,12,12:59,27,3.375,308177
2013,02,06,13,13:59,34,4.25,308211
2013,02,06,14,14:59,32,4,308243
```

I would like to graph **kWh** and **Savings** on the y-axis and the Time along the x-axis.  Any help would be appreciated.  I am using the standard code for importing a CSV file for Highcharts, but am sure I need to change it somehow.  Thanks!

```
    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            defaultSeriesType: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Wind Turbine Hourly Production'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: []
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'kWh'
            }
        },
        series: []
    };

    /*
     Load the data from the CSV file. This is the contents of the file:

        Apples,Pears,Oranges,Bananas,Plums
        John,8,4,6,5
        Jane,3,4,2,3
        Joe,86,76,79,77
        Janet,3,16,13,15

     */ 
    $.get('medford-hour.csv', function(data) {
        // Split the lines
        var lines = data.split('\n');
        $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
            var items = line.split(',');

            // header line containes categories
            if (lineNo == 0) {
                $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                    if (itemNo > 0) options.xAxis.categories.push(item);
                });
            }

            // the rest of the lines contain data with their name in the first position
            else {
                var series = { 
                    data: []
                };
                $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                    if (itemNo == 0) {
                        series.name = item;
                    } else {
                        series.data.push(parseFloat(item));
                    }
                });

                options.series.push(series);

            }

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your own parser. Here is simple example how could this look like:

```
var lines = data.split('\n');
$.each(lines, function (lineNo, line) {
    var items = line.split(',');
    if(lineNo !== 0) {
       var x = + new Date(items[1]+'/'+items[2]+'/'+items[0]+' '+items[4]),
           kwh = parseFloat(items[5]),
           savings = parseFloat(items[6]);
        if(!isNaN(kwh) && !isNaN(savings)){
            options.series[0].data.push([x,kwh]);
            options.series[1].data.push([x,savings])
        }
    }
}
```

And jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9a7wfys8/

Comment: your fiddle link is broken

Comment: Thanks @George2.0Hope ! Updated the demo. Note: It's an old answer. Nowadays I recommend using [`data`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data) module to load CSV